# How to use modal dialog in this case?

Tags: javafx, directory, dialog

I have a question. I need to make a GridPane with a directory choose that will then lead me to a modal dialog showing photos. I cannot figure how to do the modal dialog that also has to be a GridPane or a HBox...so the question is , how do I get to show a Modal Dialog after selecting the Folder and pressing the "Show" Button... Thanks a lot!

````
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FotoView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        TextField tf = new TextField();
        Button b1 = new Button("Search");
        Button b2 = new Button("Show");     
        DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();
        GridPane gp = new GridPane();   


        gp.add(tf, 0 , 0);
        gp.add(b1, 1, 0);
        gp.add(b2, 0, 1);
        b1.setOnAction(e-> dc.showDialog(primaryStage));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gp))    ;
        primaryStage.show();

}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Below is a quick example where a first window has a button that opens up a `DirectoryChooser`. Once a directory has been selected a second smaller window opens up with the Modality set to `APPLICATION_MODAL`. In this second window you could add the image(s) that you load and add them to the `GridPane`.

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage aStage) throws Exception {

        final HBox root = new HBox();
        final Button browseBtn = new Button("Click to open a Directory chooser");
        root.getChildren().add(browseBtn);

        browseBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            final DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
            final File dir = chooser.showDialog(aStage);
            openNewModalStage(aStage, dir);
        });

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        aStage.setScene(scene);
        aStage.show();
    }

    private void openNewModalStage(final Stage aStage, final File aDirectory) {
        final Stage stage = new Stage();
        final GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(grid);

        grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black");
        grid.setPrefWidth(400);
        grid.setPrefHeight(400);

        // get your images from 'aDirectory' and add them to your grid pane.
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // set the new windows Modality.
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

This way you would only need the one button and the dialog would show as soon as you've selected a directory. However, if you would still want a Search and Show button then just store the directory as a variable and add a listener on the 'show' button and move the openNewModalStage call to that one and remove the second argument.

**Edit:**
Also, depending on how many images and exactly what you want to display in the modal window, you might want to reconsider the `GridPane` and use a `TilePane`, or an hbox/vbox inside of a scroll pane. It's just a thought but I don't know what you will be doing with the `GridPane`.

Comment: I figured out another way , but your method also sounds interesting and I will give it a try.... this is a homework and I have to show images from a folder into a modal dialog, so I have to make a new class with the modal dialog and set up a hbox/vbox/grid pane or whatever. In any case I appreciate your help and as I said I will definitely give it a try ;) cheers

Comment: also, another question... is there any way to make the path of the directory available to the file input stream in the other  public class where I made the HBox? so from the main class to be accessed in the other class

Comment: You could always store the path as a variable and then do with as you please. You can create a public get method that the first class could get the path from or you could just pass it to the class that needs it once you've received a valid path. I would suggest that you ask a new question with a [mcve] that includes your different classes (without any unnecessary code) if you need more help :) best of luck!

Comment: `HBox/Vbox` inside a `ScrollPane`, `GridPane` and `TilePane` are probably not a good idea if there are a lot of images. If there are a lot of images, `ListView`, `TableView`, or `ControlsFX's` `GridView` would be better options. They are virtualized nodes. They will be way lighter on your computer's memory.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I am on it again :D